# "Confidence Intervals" with *very* small samples.

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I am collecting performance data for an application, I gather results each version.

Given that the measurement is imprecise, I'd like to calculate a confidence interval for the performance data.

Issue 1:
With multiple measurements I can apply a CI with a t distribution, as recommended for sample sizes less than 30. However my sample size is actually 2-4, is that too small?

Issue 2:
Many builds only run the performance tests once. How could I estimate error for that? I mean, technically there's an infinite error. But that is less than useful.

Honestly, I can't remember much from my statistics days. I'd simply like to graph an upper and lower bound, and the average.

Comment: You can compute confidence intervals for any sample size. But with a small sample size, your intervals will be uncomfortably large, which as you say is less than useful. However even with just a single sample, a 95% or 99.5% confidence interval, however large and however useless, is not infinite.

Comment: Ahh yes, I got myself confused between the 1/sqrt(n) factor, and the t distribute with ν=n-1, which for n=1 would be ν=0 and a t distribution cannot have 0 degrees of freedom?

(But not a factor of 1/0 as I originally confused)